# Строгий(,) выдержанный

Tags: пунктуация

"Деловой стиль одежды - это строгий(,) выдержанный стиль".

Не нашла особых различий между словами "строгий" и "выдержанный". В данном случае это синонимы? (Если да, то получается, что запятая здесь нужна).

Спасибо!

Comment: В  данном  случае  -  синонимы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ИНФОРМАЦИЯ ИЗ ИНТЕРНЕТА

"Офисный стиль произошел от совсем молодого делового стиля, который в свою очередь взял начало из классики и пуританства Англии. Направление одно и то же, различие лишь в том, что английский стиль не допускает никаких отступлений от традиций, классика – несгибаемый вектор строгости, а официально-деловой (офисный) стиль – это микс классики и функциональности, приправленный модой".

1. По определению, выдержанный стиль - это стиль последовательный, без отклонения, не допускающий сочетания разных стилей. ВЫДЕРЖАННЫМ может быть любой стиль, в том числе деловой. В этом случае можно употребить выражение (1)"выдержанный деловой стиль".
2. СТРОГИЙ стиль - это стиль классический. Можно сказать (2) "выдержанный строгий стиль".
3. Но ведь строгая классика - это обязательно выдержанный стиль, поэтому возможно СБЛИЖЕНИЕ понятий "строгий и выдержанный". Тогда можно сказать (3)"строгий, выдержанный стиль"или "выдержанный, строгий". Здесь мы имеем однородные определения, разделенные запятой.
4. Но вот выражение "Деловой стиль одежды - это строгий выдержанный стиль" без запятой представляется мне неудачным. Мы получим "выдержанный стиль", который дополнительно определяется как строгий: строгий (выдержанный стиль)
5. Можно сказать "Деловой стиль одежды - это строго выдержанный стиль", но это определение не совсем соответствует действительности, если считать, что это соединение классики и функциональности.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (ВЫВОД)

Я бы написала: "Деловой стиль одежды - это строгий, выдержанный стиль". Именно в этом значении это выражение обычно употребляется.

В некоторых случаях допустимы неоднородные отношения, например: "Деловой стиль одежды - это  выдержанный строгий (классический) стиль в своей основе, но допускающий добавления некоторых функциональных деталей.

Но не следует писать:"Деловой стиль одежды - это строгий выдержанный стиль".

Answer (score 0):

Если честно (но это сугубо субъективно) мне слово "выдержанный" в данном контексте вообще не очень нравится. Скорее "сдержанный". И все-таки оттенки качества тут есть. Скажем так, "строгий" сильнее "выдержанного-сдержанного". То есть, если первое - это обязательное деловой костюм и, как говорится, шаг влево, шаг вправо - расстрел, то второе предполагает просто отсутствие экстравагантных, ярких и кричащих деталей.
Но, повторюсь, это только мое мнение.